# Hidden status bar when presenting view controller. I'm using a navigation controller for the UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, statusbar

I have a UITableViewController with a status bar which is not hidden and I don't want it to be hidden.

When I select a UITableViewCell to go to the next detail page view controller, the status bar is still showing even though I declared for it not to be shown. Here is how I declared the status bar to be hidden in the detail view controller. But it's only hidden when it's the initial view controller, but when presented it's still shown. How can I fix it? I have added this key to my info.plist but still it didn't work.

[image: Plist Image]

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: How are you showing the new view controller? Are you using a Navigation controller?

Comment: no im not why. what do you suggest

Comment: are you suggesting I use a nagivation view controller for the detail page or table view

Comment: I'm using a navigation view controller for the table view.

Comment: what do you think emiliopelaez

Comment: We can't help you if you don't tell us how you're doing what you're doing, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: i have a navigation controller as a root to my table view and the status bar on the table view is not hidden. But when I click on a cell to present the detail page. The status bar is presented even though i called it to be hidden. Now what do I do

Comment: try clear your project. using `⌥⇧⌘K. Option-Shift- Command-K`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a new entry `View controller-based status bar appearance` with value as `NO` to info.plist.

Comment: how would i do that

Comment: am i creating a new plist liu wei

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://rshankar.com/how-to-customize-status-bar-in-ios/) can help you :)